# List Layout on Android, how to make buttons right-aligned?

Tags: android

I've been finding the way to make the buttons right-aligned, but wasn't successful. Need a little help here.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/categoryRowLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <TextView android:text="category" android:id="@+id/categoryRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </TextView>
    <Button android:text="Edit" android:id="@+id/editCategoryBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="editCategoryHandler">
    </Button>
    <Button android:text="Delete" android:id="@+id/deleteCategoryBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="deleteCategoryHandler">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/categoryRowLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <TextView android:text="category" android:id="@+id/categoryRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <Button android:text="Edit" android:id="@+id/editCategoryBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="editCategoryHandler"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/deleteCategoryBtn"
    >
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="Delete" android:id="@+id/deleteCategoryBtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="deleteCategoryHandler"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    >
        </Button>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try this, i have used relative layout and aligned delete button to right and edit button to the left of delete button.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could have just added to your TextView:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```